# Piping two bash commands in R: broken pipe error

Tags: r, bash, pipe

I'm trying to pipe two bash commands in R but I get a broken pipe error; any suggestion is appreciated.
Here's where I am:

```
#Create a long file (2GB on your drive...)
write.csv(rep(1,1E8),file="long.txt", row.names=FALSE)

system("grep 1 tmp.txt")    #This works
system("grep 1 tmp.txt| head -n 10")    #This gives a broken pipe error
```

I get grep: writing output: broken pipe
With a short file it works properly.
How can I work arround that please?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the broken pipe error when you do the same thing on the command line?

Answer (score 7):

`grep` is complaining because it has more output than 10 lines, and `head` is cutting it off before it finishes.

I suggest hiding grep's stderr output (this is where the broken pipe error is printed).

```
system("grep 1 tmp.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n 10")
```

This won't work if you need to see other errors from grep; in that case, you will need a more complicated solution.

Comment: Thanks this is usefull (will vote you up when I have enough points!) but is extremely slow: the command takes more than a min to run, while it's instantaneous in bash...

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but I don't see any reason why it would be any slower if you're running the exact same command in both places.  It probably won't help, but you can also try: `system("bash -c 'grep 1 tmp.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n 10'")` which will force `system` to use bash (in case it's using something else).

Comment: Shouldn't head be sending a SIGPIPE rather than just exiting?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: there is an error thrown but it seems to be by grep, not head

Comment: Actually @mrb back to your first point: why does this work with a small file? You can have more lines than head cares about in some cases it seems.

Comment: It comes down to buffer sizes, I believe. If grep finishes its output before head closes the pipe, grep won't complain. The error occurs when grep doesn't get a chance to finish first, which is most common when it fills the pipe buffer and pauses to wait for it to clear up (so it can write more results to it), but then head closes the pipe, leaving grep with nowhere to output.

Comment: jordanm, I believe SIGPIPE is sent to grep because head has closed the pipe; head doesn't actually send it.  Receiving SIGPIPE allows grep to stop blocking on a `write()` that can no longer finish.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to cut the error output alltogether, which is what I suspect to cause the slowness of the command...

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if your implementation of `grep` supports it, you could use

```
grep -m 10 PATTERN FILE
```

Partial description from: `man grep` on Ubuntu 12.04

```
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
      Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.
```

This option was also available on my Red Hat 5.8 box where I was having a similar issue.